# Sending messages to Kafka with header using KafkaProducer

Tags: kafka-producer-api

i am trying to create a simple utility to publish messages to Kafka, but need to pass headers as well along with the message.
The utility works fine without headers but while trying to send headers i am getting error.

below is sample code that i am using -

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "host:port");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());

        KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);

        List<Header> headers = Arrays.asList(new RecordHeader("sample_header", "sample_value".getBytes()));
        ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>("TEST", 0, "key", "sample message", headers);
        Future<RecordMetadata> future = producer.send(record);
        System.out.println(future.get());

        producer.close();

    }
```

the exception i am getting is -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Magic v1 does not support record headers
    at org.apache.kafka.common.record.MemoryRecordsBuilder.appendWithOffset(MemoryRecordsBuilder.java:385)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.record.MemoryRecordsBuilder.appendWithOffset(MemoryRecordsBuilder.java:424)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.record.MemoryRecordsBuilder.append(MemoryRecordsBuilder.java:481)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.record.MemoryRecordsBuilder.append(MemoryRecordsBuilder.java:504)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerBatch.tryAppend(ProducerBatch.java:106)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.RecordAccumulator.append(RecordAccumulator.java:219)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:791)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:745)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:634)
    at com.test.kafka.KafkaProducerApp.main(KafkaProducerApp.java:45)
```

Comment: which version of Kafka?

Comment: kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1 is the version of kafka broker

Comment: @Paizo- kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1 is the version of kafka broker .. any suggestions??

Comment: nope sorry, maybe you are using a different library version?  Here you can find some info https://stackoverflow.com/q/47953901/3224238 Why headers instead of keys?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error through different means (Spring Cloud Streams Kafka producers). My issues was caused by having an `inter.broker.protocol.version` which was set to a lower version then the version of the broker itself [see Kafka's broker configs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs) it allows:

> Specify which version of the inter-broker protocol will be used. This is typically bumped after all brokers were upgraded to a new version.

For my deployment the broker was `v1.1` but the `inter.broker.protocol.version` was `v0.10.1`. When the `v1.1` broker received a message with the headers it was fine until it went to replicate the message using `v0.10.1` which doesn't support headers (producing the error of `"Magic v1"`).