# Error throwing while producing message to kafka topic using producer API?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I need to post the consumer record  data to kafka topic using producer, While posting it was throwing an **error** :

> Magic v1 does not support add headers...

I checked the broker version also and changed into  old jar version. But it always shows an error. for consumer and producer same bootstrap servers host am using, below code I tried

kafka client version is 2.0.1 zkclient version is 0.10

consumer code  `sender` is method name

`for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
sender(record.key(), record.value());
}`

producer code :

```java
public static void sender(String key, String Value) throws Exception {
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
props.put("key.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(props);
ProducerRecord<String, String> prodrecord = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(TopicName, key, Value);
producer.send(prodrecord);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: From what I see, you're instantiating a producer for each record you read , it seems not normal to me.. Are you sure of the code you did post ?

Comment: @Yannick yes...!! It's there any problem in producer code I don't think so..!!

Comment: yes first, you should instantiate your producer before the loop and then call send only in the loop

Comment: @Yannick ok but my question is why it was throwing magic v1 does not support record headers exception...??

Comment: What is the version of your kafka broker ? Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55710773/getting-magic-v1-does-not-support-record-headers-when-producing-message) and the answer in its comment

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel broker version 0.10

Comment: Then it's a duplicate of the question I linked, you need to upgrade your broker

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel no I tried everything...!! Without upgrading how to achieve that..!! Any possible way to avoid headers while producing message